# References for topological strings on supermanifolds

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

**This question concerns topological string theory.**

It was known sice its [outset](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104162092), that the BRST-cohomology ("the ring of observables") of the weakly coupled B-model topological string on a Calabi-Yau threefold $X$ is identified with the ordinary Dolbeault cohomology ring of $X$.

**My trouble:**

I'm reading the famous Witten's paper [Perturbative Gauge Theory As A String Theory In Twistor Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312171)
. The basic construction of this paper involves the B-model with the Super-Calabi-Yau space $\mathbb{CP}^{3|4}$ as its target space. I find the paper wonderful, but **I'm struggling with what I should understand by "Dolbeault supercohomology" or "superhomology" in this, and the broader context of supermanifolds.** To be specific, I want to learn about this in order to rigorously and systematically compute (if possible) the general allowed observables in the aforementioned context. My goal is to understand more systematically how the brane spectrum is computed for string theories over supermanifolds such as the case considered in [N=2 strings and the twistorial Calabi-Yau](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0402128).

**Questions:**

1. I'm asking for your kind help to find a an introductory text, notes or papers to adquire basic practical knowledge on the field of supergeometry, specifically, on the analogue of the de Rham "homology" of a supermanifold.
2. Does anyone know if is it possible to explicitly compute the allowed branes in the case of the B-model over $\mathbb{CP}^{3|4}$ by means of homological/cohomological/worldsheet computations?

**Observation:** I'm aware of the fact that B-model branes must be strictly defined as elements of the derived bounded category of coherent sheaves on $X$ as was firstly pointed out by [Douglas](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0011017). But I will be happy just with a resource recommendation for "superhomology". In any case, and if possible, I would also sincerely appreciate any comment about the analogues of sheaf cohomology, Fukaya categories or stacks in the realm of supergeometry. I really love this field and it would be great to have references for the future.

Any comment or suggestion is helpful.

**Note**: This question was posted in MathOverflow ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366520/references-for-superhomology)) without too much success.

Comment: Concerning supergeometry and extension of De Rham theory one may have a look at the following review https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2680.